# Simple Decoder without bitset/vectors(Steganography)

Tags: c++, xcode

My encoder doesn't encode the message can someone tell me why? or how to fix it? I don't want any bitset or vectors. I tried decoding multiple times but I couldn't find the message. Can someone tell me what I'm missing? Apparantley it's the decoder then, can you guys check?

Encoder

```
#include "BitmapHelper.h"
#include <string>

void encodeMessage( unsigned char*** imageData, int imageWidth, int imageHeight){
    int i, j, c;
    int *messageASCII=nullptr;
    int **messageBinary=nullptr;
    cout << "Please enter the message you want embedded in this image (Letter)" << endl;
    char message;
    cin >> message;

    //Allocate memory for messageASCII
    messageASCII =new int[c];
    //Allocate memory for messageBinary
    messageBinary=new int *[c];
    for (int ctr=0; ctr<c; ctr++){
        messageBinary[ctr]=new int [8];
    }
    
    //Binary Conversion of message
    int m[8];
    for(int k=0; k<8; k++) {
        m[k]=message%2;
        message = message/2;
    }
    int top, bottom;
    for(bottom=0,top =7; bottom<8; bottom++,top--){
        cout << m[top];
    }
    cout << endl;
    
    //Replace LSB using bitwise operations
    for (int row = 0; row < imageHeight; row++){
        for (int col = 0; col < imageWidth; col++){
            for (int channel = 0; channel < 3; channel++){
                imageData[row][col][channel]= char((imageData[row][col][channel] &~1) | m[top]);
                top++;
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Decoder

```
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
void decodeMessage( int imageHeight, int imageWidth, unsigned char*** imageData){
    int bitcount =0;
    string message;
    for (int row = 0; row < imageHeight; row++){
        for (int col = 0; col < imageWidth; col++){
            for (int channel = 0; channel < 3; channel++){
                int (imageData[row][col][channel] %2);
                int i;
                char array[i];
                for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                {
                    int bit;
                    if (imageData[row][col][channel]%2){
                        bit =1;
                    }
                    else {
                        bit =0;
                    }
                    array[bitcount] = bit;
                    if (bitcount==8){
                        bitcount =0;
                    }
                    int total;
                    for (i=0; i<8; i++){
                        total+=pow(2,i)*array[i];
                    }
                    message += (char)total;
                    cout << message;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your title says "with bitset/vectors" and then you say "I don't want any bitset or vectors." Which is it? You say there's a problem with decoding but I only see an encoding function.

Comment: Without*** I dont want bitset or vectors

Comment: "Can someone tell me what I'm missing?" you are missing bitsets and vectors.

Comment: I don't see any immediate logical flaw with your code. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There could be an error in your `decodeMessage` method and I really hope you don't save the image to jpeg before reloading it for decoding. Can you also streamline your code? If you're just embedding one character, just do `message = 'a';` and leave out all the inputs, prints, `messageASCII`, and whatnot.

Comment: I put up my decoder maybe something is wrong with that?

Comment: I've put back the `encodeMessage` method because you need both. You didn't streamline your code as per my previous suggestion. The less noise there is in your code, the more likely it is people will go through it. You also should explicitly state what wrong output you get and what you expected instead. Saying "my program doesn't work" isn't clear enough.